# Eclipse: Where are the templates stored?

Tags: eclipse, abap-adt

I am using Eclipse in combination with the ABAP Development Tools (ADT) as main plugin for SAP-development.
Now I created some additional templates (View: Templates) and I just want to know where they are stored as I lost some of the templates and I want to check if I can find them in a backup somewhere (on file structure level).

Are the (additional created) templates as well stored in the workspace? Eclipse/ADT deliver also some basic templates, where are they stored?

Thank you for helping me to find the correct folder/file where this information is stored.

Comment: The _Preference Recorder_ might be helpful for that: see preferences _Oomph > Setup Tasks > Preference Recorder_.

Comment: I do not have these entries in the preferences

Comment: _Oomph Preferences Management_ can be installed from the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest`](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest).